# GCP user with "DNS Administrator" role cannot create record sets anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I have an Google account equipped with the "DNS Administrator" role that can suddenly not create record sets through "Add Record Set" in Google Cloud DNS anymore, via the console, since a couple of days. The project owner is able to, though. No specific error is returned by the console, only "Failed to load":

[image]

I can easily reproduce the error: add a new account to that project, assign it the "DNS Administrator" role, and keep getting that quite unexplaining "Failed to load" error.

Any hint on what to look at?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this issue is with "DNS Administrator" role. To add a record dns.changes.create and dns.resourceRecordSets.create roles on the project is required --------> basically to create/update/delete an record

As per [GCP documentation on roles](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/access-control#roles) Role roles/dns.admin title DNS Administrator has dns.changes.*  which should include create/update/delete

I have tried it myself and working fine.My test account had following roles
DNS Administrator
Security Admin
Logs Viewer

I would suggest trying it in incognito mode. Seems like some other issue effecting your project.